# Very High CTR for interstitial ads

Tags: android, admob, interstitial, facebook-audience-network

I am getting very high CTR (10-15%) on some of my apps. This applies to interstitial ads only. Has anyone faced similar issue before?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming?

Comment: How should I solve it then @jrswgtr ? Also, can I use templates for interstitial ads? I want to have some padding to avoid accidental clicks.